# Automate creating Terraform resources based on Ansible inventory

Tags: ansible, gitlab, terraform

This is a hard issue that I'm struggling with right now.
I have 3 repos:
1 - Ansible code to deploy multiple parts of an application
2 - Inventory for Ansible
3 - Terraform files to create Datadog dashboards

So far after a new server is deployed we run repo nr1 with tasks to install / configure applications on a new server. All variables such as IPs, service list were fetched from an inventory from repo nr2.

We also created multiple Datadog dashboards for those servers with hardcoded and added manually values like hostname or server pretty name as alias.

We would like to implement something like:
new server is added to the inventory with new branch
ansible runs and installs/configures application on a new server
after it ends it calls terraform to create new resources [dashboards] from inventory variables [hostname + pretty name only].

I did some research already but it turns out there is a lot of information to CREATE new inventory based on Terraform resources. I'd like to do this the other way.

FYI - all is done on Gitlab CI/CD. We also call all ansible deployments via Postman call.

The most problem I have actually is how to create a list of all servers and than create new resource based on a missing server from the entire list [inventory].

Any clues?

Terraform code [only fetching hostname from hardcoded values]

```
widget {
        timeseries_definition {
          title          = "CPU idle [%]"
          legend_columns = ["avg", "min", "max", "value", "sum"]
          request {
            dynamic "formula" {
              for_each = var.servers
              content {
                alias              = formula.value.server_hostname
                formula_expression = "default_zero(query) * 8"
              }
            }
            dynamic "query" {
              for_each = var.servers
              content {
                metric_query {
                  name  = "query"
                  query = "max:system.net.cpu_idle{host:${query.value.server_hostname}}"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: You are trying to achieve kind of the opposite that what I would expect a normal flow to be. The said normal flow would be: Create VMs via terraform > Provision said machine via Ansible; in a Terraform local-exec; post creation; possibly using a [dynamic inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/amazon/aws/docsite/aws_ec2_guide.html), in Ansible.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε is completely correct. More specific to your use case here is that with what you want to achieve it is unclear why you would want to integrate TF and Ansible here. If the dashboards are persistently managed, then you would use TF. If the dashboards are not persistently managed, then you would use Ansible. It sounds like you have a mix of the two types, and therefore may need to split them out.

Comment: I understand. And that's why I'm struggling with creating a proper workflow - no information out there because it's the opposite!

The goal for me would be to run ansible to configure/install applications on a server. Once that is done - add that server [hostname basically] to TFE and run TFE pipeline to create new resource.